# What‘s the practical use of DataStream#assignAscendingTimestamps

Tags: apache-flink

The javadoc for the DataStream#assignAscendingTimestamps

`* Assigns timestamps to the elements in the data stream and periodically creates
    * watermarks to signal event time progress.
    *
    * This method is a shortcut for data streams where the element timestamp are known
    * to be monotonously ascending within each parallel stream.
    * In that case, the system can generate watermarks automatically and perfectly
    * by tracking the ascending timestamps.`

This method assumes `that the the element timestamp are known to be monotonously ascending within each parallel stream`. But in practice, almost no stream can give such guarantee that event timestamps are in ascending order.

I would like to conclude that this method should never be used,but I would ask if I have missed something(eg, when to use it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally I agree, it can be rarely used in practice. An exception is the following: If Kafka is used as a source with LogAppendTime, timestamp are in order per-partition. You can then use per-partition watermarking in Flink [1] with the AscendingTimestampExtractor and will have pretty optimal watermarking.

Cheers,

Konstantin

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-timestamp-extractionwatermark-emission

Comment: Thanks @snntrable for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code `DataStream#assignAscendingTimestamps`, it is using `AscendingTimestampExtractor` to extract the timestamp.

`AscendingTimestampExtractor` will keep the largest event timestamp seen so far. If the event time is out of order, it will print a log to warn that monotonously ascending timestamps is violated.

So, I think this class may be handy in practice for the case that doesn't allow laziness(the watermark may keep growing).